# Ошибка парсинга через AngleSharp ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, xamarin, anglesharp

По нажатию кнопки вызывается метод

```
   private async void ParseInfoLeftNick()
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync("https://warthunder.ru/ru/community/userinfo/?nick=_____BO_____");

        string lionEarned = document.All.Where(m =>
    m.LocalName == "li" &&
    m.HasAttribute("class") &&
    m.GetAttribute("class").Contains("profile-stat__list-item")
    ).ElementAt(15).TextContent.ToString();
        TextSearch.SetText(lionEarned, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    }
```

Но при развертывании на устройстве (Android Xamarin) появляется ошибка
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

В то же время аналогичный код в Windows Form работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Кстати, установленное приложение на телефоне парсит нужное число. Но в отладке ошибка. Может что то с visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Во время дебага инет на телефоне был отключен)

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что косяк тут:

```
.ElementAt(15).
```

Вы уверены, что по 15 индексу всегда будет какое-то значение?
Например, ваше предыдущие селекторы могли ничего не найти=> вернуть пустую коллекцию, а вы пытаетесь обратится к индексу, которого нет.

Comment: Там их более 50 ти. И без отладки парсинг проходит, ошибка тольо в отладке. Еще попробую /bin и /obj удалить

Comment: Ну... чудес не бывает. Посмотрите в дабаге, какие значение возвращаются до вызова 15 индекса. Проверьте документ в дабаге, где произошел краш, так как может быть на сайте защита от обращений с 1 айпи с малыми интервалами.

Comment: ничего не менял, утром код работает, даже при многократном парсинге, но иногда вылетает исключение. Я так понимаю что парсер может не загрузить сайт и возвращает пустую коллекцию. Проблема скорее всего в сайте